# Installing the Qt SDK shows the message: cannot execute binary file

Tags: c++, qt, sdk

My environment is Linux 11.04
When I want to install Qt SDK
I download the SDK:`qt-creator-linux-x86_64-opensource-2.5.2.bin`

I move this file to `/opt`

and then

```
chmod u+x qt-creator-linux-x86_64-opensource-2.5.2.bin
./qt-creator-linux-x86_64-opensource-2.5.2.bin
```

but it shows that: cannot execute binary file

I think whether if it is because my Ubuntu is belong to 32-bit architecture

so I download `qt-creator-linux-x86-opensource-2.5.2.bin`
also move it to `/opt` file

and give the command:

```
chmod u+x qt-creator-linux-x86-opensource-2.5.2.bin
./qt-creator-linux-x86-opensource-2.5.2.bin
```

The same message still shows.

I give another command:

```
sudo ./qt-creator-linux-x86-opensource-2.5.2.bin
```

but it shows that `Syntax error: ")" unexpected`

how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Note, that is *not* the SDK, that is just Qt Creator. And an old one at that! I suggest you download the latest [Qt Online Installer for Linux 32-bit](http://qt-project.org/downloads), and use that to install whatever you want. Alternatively, just `apt-get install qtcreator` (and also any Qt development packages you want, use `apt-cache search ....`).

Comment: Thank you, it sounds that I make a mistake

Comment: I have install a Qt creator which comes from the link you give to me, and now I want to create a new project.
However Qt tells me that: please add a Qt version in Tool/Options or via the maintenance tool of the SDK.
So I now need a SDK of  Qt, but I cannot find the SDK of Qt
Can you help me?

Comment: Either use the *Qt Online Installer* to install Qt versions, or install Ubuntu's Qt development packages (I don't have an Ubuntu handy so I can't give you exact `apt-get install ...` command, sorry). Then if Qt Creator does not autodetect a Qt version, you need to add one manually. But really, the easy way is to just use the *Online installer* and select the Qt version you want, it should be autodetected by Qt Creator installed with same installer.